# Can I make a bootable Mac OS USB drive with access to a Windows PC and Inernet but no running Mac?

Tags: windows, macos, boot, usb-flash-drive, macbook-air

I've inherited a MacBook Air with no internal drive that is otherwise working and has been diagnosed at the Apple Store Genius Bar.

I don't have access to any other Mac but I have Windows PCs and Internet access.

Is there some way to download a bootable Mac OS image and copy it to a USB stick using only a Windows PC?

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this... You will be able to boot onto the USB after running the Internet Recovery Tool. https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201314

1. Boot into the Internet Recovery by holding command + R.

   1. Using the disk utility, click on the USB Device.
   2. After clicking the connected USB device, format it to Mac Extended Journaled Hard Drive.
   3. Click apply or whatever it may say.
   4. Go back to the last screen.
2. Click on "Download OS X" (at this point, you are installing OS X to the USB and the installer should be straightforward from there.

Comment: I am hoping to try this. I didn't know about it when I first posted the question here. Unfortunately my Wi-Fi access is behind a portal thing I have to log into via a web browser. I've read several pages about this and viewed a few videos but it was unclear whether I might need a password to initiate the download.

Comment: Internet recovery is the way to go, but it doesn't work behind a captive portal (https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201314). You'll need to get WiFi elsewhere or rig up some sort of connection sharing with a phone or the Windows machine.

Comment: I was actually able to log into the captive portal at the point the installer/restorer gave me the option to look for help online with Safari. It's been stalled at "23 minutes" for a long time now but that seems to be common ...

Answer (score -3):

Step 1) partition your USB flash drive with GPT
Step 2) Get the .dmg image of OS X you plan to install ready
Step 3) Download [tramsmac](http://www.acutesystems.com/scrtm.htm) and copy the .dmg to your usb
Step 4) Insert USB into mac, hold down option on boot then select the USB

Comment: yet you didn't see fit to share those instructions here... while the link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: The linked article doesn't tell me where/how I can obtain the DMG file of OSX. I can use the googles too but I can't find for sure if I can get an official copy of any version of OSX for free using a Windows PC. There are pages and I can't tell if they're fake and there are links to iTunes URLs but no download links from there. Maybe that only works from a Mac or is only for upgrades? Still using both the googles and the stack exchanges trying to fill in those blanks ...

Comment: Make it easy on yourself and install Ubuntu on your usb stick. You may also want to install REfit (http://refit.sourceforge.net/).